# gglot plot scale_fill_hue(): keep same colours for same values when comparing a subgroup with fewer categories

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing

I wish to compare two bar graphs; one represents the entire population, the other is a subgroup of the population. I quite like the colours provided by scale_fill_hue() for this, but I have run into a problem.
The factor I'm using for the fill has 6 levels: 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, and N. In the population, all six of these levels are represented, but in the subgroup, there are zero individuals with "20". This has caused the colours in scale_fill_hue() to shift over. Code for graphs is at the bottom.

[population graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Ic0.jpg)

[sample graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdXXL.jpg)

this means that red, the colour which represents "20" in my population graph, represents "50" in my subgroup graph. This is confusing, especially for a side-by-side comparison. Besides, having zero observations of 20 in the sample is still important information i want to include!

Is there a way to get ggplot to include the "20", even when there aren't any observations with that value? Or do I need to manually create my palette? Does anyone have a direction I could go for that?

```
ggplot(avmim, aes(x = as.factor(sizeg), fill = killrank)) + geom_bar(position = "fill") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))+
  labs(y="proportion", x="size group",fill="kill weight",title="Syrphid Size Group Kill Weight Proportions")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("XXS","XS","S","L","XL","XXL"))+
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=0, hjust=0.5))+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Kill Weight")
#scale_fill_discrete is leftover from when I was experimenting with ways to fix this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example using the `mtcars` dataset. `expand_limits` is usually used for the `y` axis but can be used for other aesthetics too. Here used to leave room on the fill scale for any cars that might exist with 20 gears.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, group = gear, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  expand_limits(fill = 20)
```

[image]